# What's the meaning of "mind" in this sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

> Our little hero had some difficulty in lifting the burden upon his
>   back; but he at last succeeded in **getting it placed to his mind**.

This is from a English fairy tale "The history of Tom Thumb" http://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/eng/eft/eft26.htm. What's the meaning of "mind" in this sentence? I think he can't place a burden to his mind because mind is sprite.

Comment: I think it means _he used his brain and figured out a way to solve the problem_. It's very close to the expression _get your mind right_.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is this a phrase in common usage?

Comment: @YuuichiTam It's a most unusual construction and does not sound at all idiomatic. The meaning is unclear. It might mean *to his satisfaction* or *coming to terms with it*. Can you tell us more about the source?

Comment: Yes, I added the source in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowadays *to his mind* usually means *in his opinion*. But in older English one's *mind* often meant one's *wish, liking, disposition* (in fact we still use it in that sense in *I [have (it) in mind to](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/have-it-in-mind-to-do-something)* do such-and-such), especially in colloquial and dialect use. [*The English Dialect Dictionary*](https://archive.org/stream/englishdialectdi04wriguoft#page/114/mode/2up) gives a number of citations from the end of the 19th century, when the folktale collector John Jacobs published this version of the story. Jacobs edited the heaviest dialogue out of his versions, but left a good deal of it in for flavour.

I think this is in fact a dialect use, and that the meaning is that Tom succeeded in getting the burden settled *to his satisfaction*—that is, he found a reasonably comfortable way of carrying it.